# how to know if a server is listening at a port

Tags: sockets

I have created a TCP socket at one end of my application. Say the end is 1. This socket closes after about 10sec. Now the other side of my application (end 2) is allowed to connect to the above created socket.  Im coding this socket app in python, so suppose my end 2 is trying to connect to the TCP socket, but the socket no longer exists, my program terminates because of some exception. I dont want that to happen. It's like there is a while loop in my end 2. So if a connection is not available it goes back and wait.

Comment: This problem has no possible solution. You need to handle the exception and retry connection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling the exception correctly ..

```
try:
    s.connect((host,port))
except socket.error, (value,message):
    if s:
        s.close()
    print "Could not open socket: " + message
    """Code to handle a retry"""
```

On getting an error .. you can retry by doing a bind and listen again.. Also you need to have retry count ..say 5 and then perhaps exit.

Comment: having little background in the world of exception handling, does my latter part of the code run after a exception has occurred??

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html .. The documentation states that 4 types of exceptions can be caught. I think your server side socket closed exception should be caught by socket.error. Check the errno thrown and then handle accordingly.